# Does there exist a jQuery plugin or JavaScript library that allows Venn Diagram presentation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, data-visualization, jquery-plugins

I'm writing a jQuery application to allow analysis of data with the help of visual cues.  My data is retrieved via XMLHttpRequest in the form of JSON.  The visual cues include histograms, spark lines, and various other graph types.  The idea is that the user is able to narrow their data via these various visual views.

My question is thus - aside from the Google Charts API, does there exist a JavaScript way of presenting a Venn Diagram?

Requirement: no Flash.

Canvas is acceptable.

Answer (score 9):

In a word:

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: Wow, haven't ever heard of this one.  Awesome, thanks.  Not jQuery specific, but useful nonetheless. Wish I could assign two answers.

Comment: It works great with jQuery, by the way :)

Comment: Isn't Raphael just a drawing lib? I don't see any ready to use Venn diagrams there.

Comment: Third Google hit for "RaphaelJS Venn" https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/pull/89

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the vector-based Raphael approach would be [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) which is canvas-based.  That said, Raphael is a very nice drawing library as well.

Comment: True, but Raphael has support for IE, while processing.js does not, and also uses SVG/VML, which are "true" DOM elements that support DOM events.

Comment: I'm not arguing the merits of one over the other, just presenting an alternative; I personally prefer vector-based graphics any day. IE can be supported easily via Google's excanvas (http://excanvas.sourceforge.net).

Comment: Wow, I'm a little surprised that I didn't think of processing.js - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have been playing around a d3js based solution:

https://github.com/sidoh/venn

Hope it helps!